# Function Prototypes with multi-dimensional arrays as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, declaration

Brand new to C, I come from a Java background.

I am having an issue where I can't compile because the compiler wants to know at compile time the size of my array. For example, I want to print my array to the console. It won't allow me to declare a function prototype as such:

```
void printRoom(char[][], int, int); //not allowed
```

What am I supposed to do instead? Is there not a way around this? Online resources that I have found seem to indicate that I MUST know the  dimensions if I want to use a function prototype. It appears that it also requires that the function header have the size of the array as well.

```
void printRoom(char room[][], int height, int width){ // not allowed, missing array bounds
```

Would a valid solution to this problem just be to say the array is of size 1000*1000 (the maximum array size I can expect)? That seems sloppy to me but I'm pretty sure it would work as long as I stayed within the bounds of what the array size is actually supposed to be.

I am NOT interested in pointers and malloc at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the compiler supports variable length arrays then you can declare the function the following way

```
void printRoom( int, int, char[*][*]);
```

or just

```
void printRoom( int, int, char[][*]);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printRoom( int, int, char[*][*]); 

void printRoom( int m, int n, char a[m][n] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%3s ", a[i] );
        putchar( ' ');
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}   

int main(void) 
{
    const int M = 2;
    const int N = 10;
    char a[M][N];

    strcpy( a[0], "Hello" ),
    strcpy( a[1], "World" );

    printRoom( M, N, a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello  World
```

If the compiler does not support VLAs then the number of columns has to be a constant. For example

```
#define N 100

//...

void printRoom(char[][N], int, int);
```

Comment: Ah it does support it (in C89). However it still requires that I declare the size in the function. I will already know this so it won't be a problem, but do you know of another way I could accomplish this without knowing the size while passing into a function?

Comment: @frillybob If you do not know the sizes of the array then you should use either VLAs or dynamically allocate an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard says in §6.7.6.3 **Function declarators (including prototypes)**:

> ¶12 If the function declarator is not part of a definition of that function, parameters may have
>   incomplete type and may use the `[*]` notation in their sequences of declarator specifiers
>   to specify variable length array types.

That's standard-speak for: *You can write a function declaration, but not the function definition, using a notation such as:*

```
void printRoom(int, int, char [*][*]);
```

where the arguments are re-ordered in the declaration because in the function definition, you must specify the sizes before you specify the array:

```
void printRoom(int height, int width, char room[height][width])
{
    …
}
```

You could reverse the order of `height` and `width` in the function, but normally in C you'd name the dimensions in the order they're used.
You're not obliged to specify the size of the leading dimension; all the others must have a size associated with them.  That means you could write:

```
void printRoom(int, int, char [][*]);
```

and:

```
void printRoom(int height, int width, char room[][width])
{
    …
}
```

The function still needs to know the height so that it can process the array accurately, but it doesn't have to be part of the array definition.

> §6.9.1 **Function definitions**
>
> ¶10 On entry to the function, the size expressions of each variably modified parameter are
>   evaluated and the value of each argument expression is converted to the type of the
>   corresponding parameter as if by assignment. (Array expressions and function
>   designators as arguments were converted to pointers before the call.)

Your `room` is a variably-modified parameter.